# Trying to upload a file to OneDrive from iOS. What's wrong with my request?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsmutableurlrequest, onedrive

I'm trying to upload a file to `OneDrive` using `BITS` protocol. The documentation describes a request to be like this:

[image]

The complete documentation page is here:[OneDrive Large File Uploads](https://gist.github.com/rgregg/37ba8929768a62131e85)

Actually it deals with uploading files by chunks but since a size of chunk must be not greater than 60 MB I'm trying to upload a small file as a single chunck. Here's my code:

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"download" ofType:@"jpeg"];
    self.data      = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

    NSString *boundary  = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"image\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:self.data]];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    length = body.length;

    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString]];
    urlRequest.HTTPMethod           = @"POST";

    [urlRequest setValue:@"BITS_POST" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Http-Method-Override"];
    [urlRequest setValue:self.accessToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [urlRequest setValue:self.sessionId forHTTPHeaderField:@"BITS-Session-Id"];
    [urlRequest setValue:@"Fragment" forHTTPHeaderField:@"BITS-Packet-Type"];
    [urlRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [urlRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0-%d/%d", length - 1, length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Range"];

    urlRequest.HTTPBody = body;

    self.uploadConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

Whatever I try I receive 400 error and `BadArgument` as `X-ClientErrorCode`. Parameters `self.accessToken` and `self.sessionId` are valid, they are just received from the SDK. I have no idea what's wrong there. Can anyone please help me? What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was the "Content-Range" was incorrect - it needed to include "bytes" in front of the range.

**Original Answer**

It doesn't look like you're sending either the Create-Session request before the Fragment, nor the Close-Session request after the Fragment. You'll need to create the session before sending fragments even if you're only planning on sending a single one. If you know you'll only be sending a single fragment it's better to use a direct upload to avoid unnecessary round trips:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn659726.aspx#upload_a_file

Comment: I did create the session, Brad! Look, I'm using the session id. no problems with creating a session, works like charm. And I need to upload chunks (I tried it too, with the same result, here I'm using one file just as a single chunk, I thought it doesn't matter in this case), so I don't need direct upload, i need BITS. Did you ever do that in iOS?

Comment: Bah, sorry I just assumed this was the entire repro and didn't notice the session id! :D

Can you try with a straight body and not with boundaries?

Comment: I already did. I tried without boundaries. still 400. i tried everything, I've spent 6 hours today without luck. did you ever do that in any language? I just need a working example.

Comment: It might be your Content-Range header... try adding "bytes" in front of the range (E.g. "bytes 0-%d/$d")

Comment: Brad, that was the case!!! You're my saviour! Edit your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Brad, a weird thing is happening. The server gives me 401 error for Create-Session request. I don't know why, I changed nothing. 401 is authorization so there must be something wrong with access token. but it accepts access token when make a request for user id. what may be the reason for that? I hate to disturb you, but I really need help.

Comment: And I fixed that by creating a new OneDrive account and signing in with a new user. And it returned me the session id. After that I logged out from the new user and signed in with the old one. And again it returned me the session id, everything went well. Why so? Do you know? How to avoid that?

Comment: Brad, I wanna ask you one more question (please forgive me for disturbing you so much). I assume one cannot upload the chunks concurrently. Only in sequence one after another. Am I right?

Comment: For your 401 issue I'm not sure - maybe the token expired and needs to be renewed, but it's acceptable for making a request for user id? If it happens repeatedly start another question on that one. For the concurrency question the answer is no, currently chunks must be uploaded sequentially and in order.

Comment: Brad, please take a look at this question of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27600577/uploading-files-to-onedrive-401-error