# Uploading files to OneDrive results in a 401 error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, http, onedrive

I'm implementing uploading big files to OneDrive by using the BITS protocol. Here is the [documentation](https://gist.github.com/rgregg/37ba8929768a62131e85).

I'm having the following issue. After a certain period of time of being logged in when I'm trying to create a session I'm receiving 401 error. Here's the complete response:

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7d6ee0f0> { URL: https://cid-da1cedf5484811a9.users.storage.live.com/items/DA1CEDF5484811A9!373/IMG_0003.JPG } { status code: 401, headers {
"BITS-Packet-Type" = Ack;
"Content-Length" = 0;
Date = "Mon, 22 Dec 2014 09:50:22 GMT";
P3P = "CP=\"BUS CUR CONo FIN IVDo ONL OUR PHY SAMo TELo\"";
Server = "Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0";
"X-AsmVersion" = "UNKNOWN; 19.9.0.0";
"X-ClientErrorCode" = AccessDenied;
"X-MSNSERVER" = "SN3301____PAP101";
"X-QosStats" = "{\"ApiId\":0,\"ResultType\":2,\"SourcePropertyId\":0,\"TargetPropertyId\":42}";
"X-ThrowSite" = "4e1b.c093";
} }
```

And here's how my request looks:

```
{
Authorization = "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";
"BITS-Packet-Type" = "Create-Session";
"BITS-Supported-Protocols" = "{7df0354d-249b-430f-820d-3d2a9bef4931}";
"X-Http-Method-Override" = "BITS_POST";
}
```

(I have omitted code used to open session because it's pretty large).

OK, the first thing that comes to my mind is that access token has got outdated and I need to renew it somehow. BUT! Just before I perform request to retrieve user Id using the same access token:

```
- (void)retrieveUserId
{
NSString                  *urlString            = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token=%@", commonAccessToken];
NSURL                     *url                  = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession              *session              = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];
NSURLSessionDataTask      *task                 = [session dataTaskWithURL:url
                                                         completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
                                                             
                                                             NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
                                                             
                                                             if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200)
                                                             {
                                                                 NSLog(@"Response retrieving user id %@", httpResponse);
                                                                 
                                                                 NSError      *parsingError     = nil;
                                                                 NSDictionary *parsedDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                                                                                  options:kNilOptions
                                                                                                                                    error:&parsingError];
                                                                 if (!parsingError)
                                                                 {
                                                                     commonUserId = parsedDictionary[@"id"];
                                                                     [self createUploadRequest];
                                                                 }
                                                                 else
                                                                 {
                                                                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                                         
                                                                         [self.delegate bitsClient:self didFailWithError:parsingError];
                                                                         
                                                                     });
                                                                 }
                                                             }
                                                             else
                                                             {
                                                                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                                     
                                                                     [self.delegate bitsClient:self didFailWithError:error];
                                                                     
                                                                 });
                                                             }
                                                         }];
[task resume];
}
```

And it works. This access token is OK when I get the user Id. But you can see that here unlike when trying to open a session the access token is put as a part of URL, not as one of header fields. I'm not sure if it matters or not. By now I can't explain such a behaviour. If I logout and login again then it's OK again, I don't receive the 401 error any more, so probably I really should renew the token, but how can it be done? One more thing for you to know - when I get the access token from `LiveConnectSession` I check if this session is expired and it's not. Its `expires` property is later than `[NSDate date]`.

Also one more thing for you to know - despite I'm not able to open session and my request is being rejected with 401 error if I try to upload files by using `Live SDK`'s `LiveOperation` the files are uploaded without any error.

I want to resume: After a certain period (seems like it is 24 hours but I'm not sure) of being logged in as OneDrive user I become unable to upload files using BITS protocol because I receive 401 error. At the same time the session seems to be not expired and I can still upload files by using `LiveOperation`. Also I can easily get user id using the same access token which is used when opening an upload session. If I logout and login again then again everything works like charm and I'm able to create session and upload files.

Answer (score 0):

The response you provided in your question definitely indicates that the issue is around authentication - specifically OneDrive is not recognizing the provided authentication. Expiration is the most likely explanation for that and so refreshing is probably the answer. If you requested the "wl.offline_access" scope, along with the others you require, you should get a "refresh_token" back as part of the OAuth 2.0 flow and as a result allow the creation of new "access_tokens" when the previous ones expire. I believe the Live SDK itself handles the refreshing process, but I'm not entirely familiar with that side of things - for now make sure that scope is requested, and we'll learn together if the SDK handles the rest :)

Comment: Brad, thank you again for the answer. Yes, I do request "wl.offline_access" scope and I can get a refresh token from the session. But I have no idea what to do with that refresh token and how to create a new access token. I couldn't find that in Google

Comment: I think things are a little convoluted here since you're only using the SDK to create the session. If this were an operation in the SDK it should handle the refresh, but since it's not... You could try creating a new LiveConnectClient once the "expires" (on LiveConnectSession) is exceeded. Assuming the refresh is persisted it should work. Also in case you weren't aware, you might find this useful https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-iOS

Comment: I will try this solution, but as I said "expires" property doesn't exceed at the moment of the error. It is still in future time

Comment: Hmm, that's strange - how much further in the future is it when you observe the authentication starting to fail?

Comment: an hour, or few hours. let's say I was playing with uploading files yesterday, it went ok, and tomorrow morning I start with it again. I start the app for the first time today, I obtain the session, I see that it "expires" property is in future. This is how I see that - [[NSDate date] compare:session.expires] == NSOrderedAscending. I can perform any operations with Live SDK, no problems, but the open uploading session request is returning 401 error

Comment: what about cookies? may it be the cause of the problem? what do you think?

Comment: Brad, I tried to create a new LiveConnectClient but it didn't work. the delegate methods were never called. nor for successful login neither for failure. just nothing. I did it like this:  self.client = [[LiveConnectClient alloc] initWithClientId:kSkyDriveClientID
                                                                        scopes:@[@"wl.signin", @"wl.skydrive", @"wl.skydrive_update", @"wl.offline_access"]
                                                                      delegate:self
                                                                     userState:@"initialize"];

Comment: Andrey, have you a resolution of a problem now?

Answer (score 0):

Andrey, i  am  php  developer  and  here  is  what i  am  doing in  php:

```
const API_URL = 'https://apis.live.net/v5.0/';
const INITAPIURL = 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf';
const URI_AUTHORIZE = 'https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf';
```

1)  getting  access  token  and  saving   refresh  token (function  below  generate URL to redirect  user  for  oAuth)

```
public function getAuthorizeUrl($cburl) {
        $cburl=_SKYDRIVE_REDIRECT_URI;
        return self::URI_AUTHORIZE.'?client_id='.urlencode(_SKYDRIVE_API_CLIENT_ID).'&scope='.urlencode('wl.offline_access wl.skydrive wl.skydrive_update wl.emails wl.contacts_skydrive wl.contacts_photos').'&response_type=code&redirect_uri='.urlencode($cburl);
    }
```

2) after  every  3300 seconds (access  token  live  for  3600 sec) i  refresh  access  token  with  refresh  token  directly  on server (without  user  confirmation in  browser)

```
$r = $this->http(self::INITAPIURL, 'POST', array("grant_type" => "refresh_token", "client_id" => _SKYDRIVE_API_CLIENT_ID, "client_secret" => _SKYDRIVE_API_SECRET, "redirect_uri" => _SKYDRIVE_REDIRECT_URI, "refresh_token" => $this->refreshtoken));
```

3)  i   am  sending  access  token as  header  with  curl  for  all my  requests   to  API  (except  token  refresh  above)

```
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer " . $this->token;
```

and  above  steps   are  working  when i  use   BITS (i  just implemented  BITS  protocol use  on  perl  and  everything  is  working)

P.S. Thank you  that  you  posted  URL   of  folder  by  ID  they  had  wrong URL  in  documentation   :)

Comment: well, for me access token seems to live significantly longer than 3600 seconds, but I'll try to refresh token as you porposed

Comment: "get  token"  or  "refresh token"   response  is  returning  token  life   time: {"token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3600,"scope":"wl.offline_access wl.skydrive wl.skydrive_update wl.emails wl.contacts_skydrive wl.contacts_photos","access_token":"EwC........"}

Comment: can you give me the value of _SKYDRIVE_REDIRECT_URI? Or should I put any?

Comment: Seems like redirect uri must be provided in the Live SDK app management site. I got it